# why angularjs controller loading twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Here is my route config, I am using routeProvider to bind controller to view and not declaring `ng-controller` in my view still my controller loading twice, I searched for lot of solutions and tried every thing but no use.

```
 $routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/home.html"
}).when("/login", {
    controller: "loginController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/login.html"
}).when("/regcars", {
    controller: "RegCarsController",
    templateUrl: "app/views/client/RegCars.html"
}).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home/" });
```

Here is template(view)

```
  <div class="col-md-6 box box-success  pull-left">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">My cars</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        {{CarName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller

```
app.controller('RegCarsController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.CarName = "MyCar";
  alert('MyCar');
});
```

In my above code showing alert twice. Below I have link to call the view, tried with and with out slash at end of href link

```
 <a href="#/regcars/">
    <i class="fa fa-car fa-2x"></i> <span>My Cars</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: are you using ng-controller tag on the top of the element

Comment: please add a JSFiddle

Comment: Are you completety sure you don't have an `ng-controller` attribute in your template, before the markup you are posting here?

Answer (score 0):

Some proof of concept that controller is called many times. Strange.

On the other hand - [the same code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p1ztybr/) -  shows that controller is executed / fired only once.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
      controller: "homeController",
      templateUrl: "app/views/home.html"
    }).when("/regcars", {
      controller: "RegCarsController",
      templateUrl: "app/views/client/RegCars.html"
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
  })
  .run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('app/views/home.html', '<div>home tempalte</div>');
    $templateCache.put('app/views/client/RegCars.html', '<div>cars template, car name: {{ CarName }}</div>');
  })
  .controller('homeController', function() {})
  .controller('RegCarsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.CarName = "MyCar";
    console.log('Called many times')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <ul><li><a href='#/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='#/regcars'>Cars</a></li></ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Runs fine for me, "Called many times" only appears once in the console.

Comment: @C14L For me - about 134 times - till console crash ; / Probably it is tight coupled with origin policy for stackoveflow domain.